# How do I disable github workflow cancellation?

Tags: github-actions

The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/canceling-a-workflow) doesn't specify how to prevent workflow cancellation, however, it'd be useful for my case.

In my opinion it would make sense to have a configuration option to either hide or disable the 'Cancel workflow' button when the given workflow is running.

Comment: Apparently, this feature is not yet implemented, for now you can only use `if: ${{ canceled() }}` or `if: ${{ always() }}` to run operations even if the workflow is canceled, note that the jobs will be killed after 5min from receiving the signal [src](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/canceling-a-workflow)

Comment: It is more than nothing so thank you for that suggestion. Hopefully it will be implemented later

Answer (score 0):

*Posting this here as an answer for visibility (please if someone from Github is reading this, update me):*

Apparently, this feature is not yet implemented, for now you can only use `if: ${{ cancelled() }}` or `if: ${{ always() }}` to run operations even if the workflow is canceled, note that the jobs will be killed after 5min from receiving the signal ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/canceling-a-workflow))

> After the 5 minutes cancellation timeout period, the server will force
> terminate all jobs and steps that don't finish running or fail to
> complete the cancellation process.

Also, as you may know: Runs can be only manually triggered and cancelled by the contributors. So you may consider limiting the access to your organisations

See:

- https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/disabling-or-limiting-github-actions-for-your-organization
- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26064